# Is saving uploaded files safe?

Tags: php, file, validation, upload, code-injection

I'm trying to build a simple image uploader using PHP. I do know how to code it, however I have a few concerns..

My question I had is the following: Is saving files which users send safe to save as the original file? With this I mean: Will I not get any vulnerabilities when I'm saving a file send by an user?

Let's say my PHP script does this: It retrieves the POST data, which includes a file send by a person on my website. Is it save to just move the file over to a directory, with original name, content, etcetera? Is there any harm in doing this, or should I rename these files to a random string?

If this isn't a safe way to do this, then what is? How would I verify the send content isn't harmful?

Comment: Pooh...is there an important reason to wite it by yourself? You can simply use the library from imagemagick.

Comment: @bub Improving my coding, learning more.. What's the point in using a library if I still don't know the answer to my question?

Answer (score 1):

There are always vulnerabilities in storing and providing content provided by a client.

This blog post gives a good description of the vulnerabilities you could face, how they're exploited and how to protect against them. I suggest you use this as a reference: http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/01/secure-file-upload-in-php-web-applications/

Comment: You should better apply a whitelist instead of a blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you only process files with the correct ending. Image files are never executed by a webserver, but .php files are for example. So make sure the users don't upload any file that can be executed.

I'm not aware of file names that are harmful. For the content this is difficult to answer. I remember an attack vector with modified TIFF images on windows and one in libjpeg on *nix Systems. However you probably won't be able to find these things without completely decoding the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach: use this (https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/03/the-shortest-image-uploader-ever/) very short Image Uploader, by Paul Rouget, based on Imgur.com's API.

Instead of uploading directly to your database, let imgur do all the security and validation, then if you need to, link to or download the (safe) image via Imgur.

It's free for non-commercial and very cheap for commercial.

Basically, you can use imgur's API to safely upload images from your HTML page, with no server side code at all

Here's a live demo: (http://paulrouget.com/miniuploader/)

Answer (score -1):

[**I would say 100% user upload file are NOT 100% SAFE**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload)

JPEG files can contain arbitrary data in them in addition to the actual image data; it's part of the spec. Thus, merely checking if an image is a valid JPEG does not mean that the file is necessarily completely harmless.

### File upload without validation

```
HTML Form:
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST"> <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" /> Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br /> <input type="submit" value="Upload File" /> </form>
PHP Code:
<?php
$target_path  =  "uploads/";
$target_path  =  $target_path  .  basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) . " has been uploaded";
} else {
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

- Define a .htaccess file that will only allow access to files with
  allowed extensions.
- Do not place the .htaccess file in the same directory where the
  uploaded files will be stored. It should be placed in the parent
  directory.
- A typical .htaccess which allows only gif, jpg, jpeg and png files
  should include the following (adapt it for your own need). This will
  also prevent double extension attacks.

  `deny from all
  <Files ~ “^w+.(gif|jpe?g|png)$”>
  order deny,allow
  allow from all
  </Files>`
- If possible, upload the files in a directory outside the server root.
  Prevent overwriting of existing files (to prevent the .htaccess
  overwrite attack).

Create a list of accepted mime-types (map extensions from these mime types).
Generate a random file name and add the previously generated extension.
Don’t rely on client-side validation only, since it is not enough. Ideally one should have both server-side and client-side validation implemented.